# Why is my Samsung NX1000 taking completely black photos and what can I do about it?

Tags: repair, samsung

Since a week or so my Samsung NX 1000 camera is capturing completely black photos. Not all of them, just about the 50%.

(The first one after switching the camera on or changing mode normally is ok)

The photos are really completely black (I am in RAW mode and checked them in Lightroom, too), no detail, no noise. So it does not seem to be a problem of underexposure.

I tried different lenses, different memory cards and even upgraded the firmware to 01.15, without success. Switching to other capture modes or changing to JPG does not help neither.

Does anyone have an idea why this might happen and what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find the issue with this? My NX1000 has started doing this, creating random black frames of nothingness. It's like its just inserting a black image as there's no noise or anything like your situation. I also get a greenish glitch that happens on preview screen but it looks fine on playback. Sometimes I get pink glitches on preview ones too but again doesn't affect the image!

Comment: @Bassquake no, unfortunately not. I still have the NX1000 here, thought in sending it for repair. But bought a new one (a small Lumix) in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your shutter gets stuck.
Switching on and off opens it, but it gets stuck close afterwards.Remove you lens. Does the shutter is closed or open?
I have an NX2000 here that also has a shutter problem. I do not have a solution yet.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that maybe the problem. Unfortunately I am not able to verify it. My shutter is always open, it just closes (and opens then) when taking pictures. I tried the "BURST" mode, where the camera takes pictures without shutter, and I did not get any black photos up to now.

Comment: Not sure still... the sound is always the same, even on black photos. What is strange as well is that some photos, when shooting in continuous (Low or High) mode are greenish previewing them (while the camera is processing), but ok afterwards.